# Apache CXF jax-ws dynamic client creation take a long time when a webservice is down

Tags: java, apache, web-services, cxf, jax-ws

We are developing an application to create dynamic clients for java soap web services (JAX-WS) and invoke an specific method of each and show results in the end by Apache CXF `JaxWsDynamicClientFactory` but the problem is it take a long while to end process of client creation when corresponding web service is down.

How can I improve performance and speed of client creation?

Thanks.

Comment: You can initialize client lazily, i.e. on first method call. Alternatively there should be a way to setup timeout for underlying http client. With dynamic WS client I assume it first tries to download and parse the WSDL file and default connection timeout is too high.

Comment: Thank you , can you guide me how to decrease initial timeout?